# Как перевести сантиметры в метры в SWIFT

Tags: swift, типы-данных, double, int

Столкнулся с задачей по SWIFT. Нужно создать переменные с определенными типами данных и приняв значения в переменные вычислить индекс массы тела.
Пример кода:

```
let name: String = “Andrew”
var weight: Double = 71.6
var height: Int = 176

var bodyMassIndex = weight / pow(Double(height), 2)
```

Столкнулся с проблемой. Результат расчета - полная ерунда. Ведь нужно ввести рост в метрах, а это будет 1.76, но тип у меня Int.
Помогите разобраться. Жутко туплю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var bodyMassIndex = weight / pow(Double(height) / 100, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

в swift есть для этого специальные методы для работы с длинной или другими единицами измерения чего либо .

вот пример для сантиметров .

```
var sm = Measurement(value: 176, unit: UnitLength.centimeters) //176 cm
```